# Whats wrong with this prolog optimization solution?

Tags: prolog, clpfd, eclipse-clp

```
solve(Amounts) :-
    Total = 1505,
    Prices = [215, 275, 335, 355, 420, 580],

    length(Prices, N),
    length(Amounts, N),
    Amounts :: 0..Total//min(Prices),
    Amounts * Prices #= Total,

    labeling(Amounts).
```

Comment: That's not SWI-Prolog. Presumably it's [tag:eclipse-prolog]

Comment: Why do you say there's something wrong with it?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with it.  It is the example from http://eclipseclp.org/examples/xkcd287.ecl.txt, and if you hadn't omitted the line

```
:- lib(ic).
```

which loads the [interval constraint solver](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/index.html), it would work just fine in [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org) Prolog.

Comment: (cf. http://xkcd.com/287/) --- ... and `lib(ic)` is what, library for integer constraints?

Comment: `lib(ic)` stands for interval constraints. It implements constraints over integers and reals (represented as floating point intervals). I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does also work in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
?- [user].
solve(Amounts) :-
    Total = 1505,
    Prices = [215,275,335,355,420,580],
    length(Prices, N),
    length(Amounts, N),
    min_list(Prices, MinPrice),
    MaxAmount is Total//MinPrice,
    Amounts ins 0..MaxAmount,
    scalar_product(Prices, Amounts, #=, Total),
    label(Amounts).
^D
?- solve(X).
X = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1] ;
X = [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].
```

But I guess its not an optimization search problem,
the objective function is missing.

Bye